# Schiit Modi 2 and Magni 2 on Ubuntu 20.04: Analog or Digital Output?

Tags: sound

I have a Schiit Modi 2 DAC and Magni 2 amp hooked up to my Thinkpad p14s AMD. The Modi 2 DAC plugs into my Thinkpad via USB, and the Magni 2 amp is connected to the Modi 2 DAC via RCA cables. My headphones (Sennheiser hd600) plug into the Magni 2 amp. In my sound settings on Ubuntu 20.04, I have two audio output options of interest (i.e. other than just the built-in headphone jack output): "Analog Output - USB Modi Device" and "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - USB Modi Device." Right now I'm using the "Analog Output - USB Modi Device" output and it sounds fine, but I'm not sure whether I should be using the "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - USB Modi Device" for better sound. I get sound out of my headphones when I select either one, but the "Digital" option is a bit louder. I assumed that with the "Analog" option the digital signal from my computer is going to the Modi 2 DAC via usb, gets converted to analog, goes to the Magni 2 amp, gets amplified, and then goes to my headphones. Is that correct? I'm confused since I'm coming from a Mac where I only had one sound output option for my Schiit setup. Should I select the "Analog" or "Digital" output option for the best sound?

Comment: Why don't you try both and decide which one sounds better to your ears or use a [spectrum analyzer](https://www.hitsquad.com/smm/linux/SPECTRUM_ANALYZERS/). I don't have any expertise in sound engineering or analysis. You may find better suggestions in audio related fora.

Comment: Let me simplify the question and remove the subjectivity of good vs. bad sound: I just want to know what the signal chain looks like when I select the different output options. Which option should I select if I want to send the digital signal from my computer over USB to my Modi 2 DAC, have the DAC convert the signal to analog, have the analog signal sent to the Magni 2 amp, have the signal amplified, and have the amplified analog signal sent to my headphones?

Comment: Please [update the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1328240/edit) with the additional information.

Comment: I'm also curious about this and I see exactly the same (I have a Modi 2, Ubuntu 20.04).
If we ignore for a moment the words "analog" and "digital", which may be misleading, I think the difference is in the protocol used to transmit data to the Modi.
According to [Schiit spec](https://www.schiit.com/products/modius), Modi 2 can handle either USB or S/PDIF as inputs.
The option with S/PDIF in the name, I assume, uses S/PDIF to talk to the Modi, the other one probably just USB?
As to which one is better not sure, probably comparable, As to whether they are called Analog and Digital, no clue